# A problem that I tried to solve with the help of strings and repetitive instructions, but on the console the result is not what I expected

Tags: c#, string, if-statement, substring

```
using System;

class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        string candidateName = Console.ReadLine();
        string input = Console.ReadLine();

        int numberOfAdmittedPersons = Convert.ToInt32(input);

        string result = string.Empty;

        for (int i = 1; i <= numberOfAdmittedPersons; i++)
        {
            string listOfAllAdmittedPersons = Console.ReadLine();
            {
                if (i != numberOfAdmittedPersons)
                {
                   result += listOfAllAdmittedPersons;
                }
            }
        }

        if (result.Contains(candidateName))
        {
           Console.WriteLine("true");
        }
        else
        {
           Console.WriteLine("false");
        }
    }
}
```

The application receives on the first line the name of a candidate C (inputted by the user). The next line contains the number of persons admitted (also inputted by the user).Then the list of all admitted persons follows, one person per line (also inputted by the user).

I have to make an application which displays "True" if candidate C was admitted (C is found in the list) or "False" if the candidate was rejected (C is not on the list)
for example : if I input :

```
John
3
George
Maria
John
```

The console will display : `true`

But the result I get is : `false`.

What can I do to correct my code?

Comment: Tested the code SBFrancies provided, everything works fine. What is the "bug" you got?

Comment: For example if  I enter MAX, 3, AMA, MAX , AMAXAVIER the result is true, because the string AMAXAVIER contains the string MAX.. but I want the names to be separated, here the result should be false.

Comment: Umm.. The second string you entered is "MAX", shouldn't it return true? And what does "names to be separated" mean?

Comment: sorry I wanted to say If I input MAX, 3, AMA, AMAXAVIER, MARIA the result is true, but it has to be false

Comment: It returns false in my test.

Comment: I tried SBFrancies code,but when I want to write result.Contains there is a compilation error.. and I don't know what is wrong

Comment: Did you get any exception? Could you provide the exception message?

Comment: the string [] does not contain a definition for 'Contains'.

Comment: Try to add this `using System.Linq;`. Here is the [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.linq.enumerable.contains?view=net-5.0).

Comment: It works. Thank you so much :) but I have another question, I could make it in another way, like without using this System.Linq ?

Comment: Sure, use a List<string>. I have posted it as a reply.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Another way is to define a list to store the names.

```
List<string> result = new List<string>();

for (int i = 0; i < numberOfAdmittedPersons; i++)
{
    //  add items 
    result.Add(Console.ReadLine());
}

if (result.Contains(candidateName))
{
   // ...
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Your code has a couple of issues. What is causing your bug is this line:

`if (i != numberOfAdmittedPersons)`
It means the last name is not being added to your string.

However there is another problem. Given the following input:

```
MAX
2
AMA
XAVIER
```

The result would be `true` as the string `AMAXAVIER` contains the string `MAX`. The answer is to use a collection, for example:

```
string[] result = new string[numberOfAdmittedPersons];

for (int i = 0; i < numberOfAdmittedPersons; i++)
{
    result[i] = Console.ReadLine();
}

if (result.Contains(candidateName))
{
...
```

Comment: If I use collection there will be a bug in this part : if (result.Contains (candidateName))